# Settings for VM using tomcat with intellij

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

What does the `-D` stand for when setting VM settings in Eclipse and ItelliJ?

Is there a way to increase the connectionTimeout for Tomcat in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a vague question. The `-D` is a JVM argument flag. It influences a named setting on the JVM rather than being passed as an argument to the main method via `public static void main(String[] args) {}`.

What "timeout" are you referring to?

- connectionLinger
- connectionTimeout
- connectionUploadTimeout
- executorTerminationTimeoutMillis
- keepAliveTimeout

I'm referring to this [document](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html) for settings that can be set via the `server.xml` configuration.

If you are referring to say an embedded container please update your question.

Comment: You answered very well.  I am referring to connectionTimeout.  I am pretty sure my request api call is timing out in IntellJ for JSON.  Can this be set by way of vm -D arguments?  My reasoning is because in Eclipse you have an option to increase the timeout.

Comment: I think I need a lot more context here. The `connectionTimeout` setting is the time from the socket opening until the request line is seen. Can you provide more detail of how you're running into this problem? Screenshots might help. Also, for reference, IntelliJ allows you to setup a Run/debug profile for Tomcat (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html) This should allow you to modify the `-D` arguments.

Comment: Dave G. the issue I am facing now is a X.509 cert issue with IntelliJ IDEA.  Due to time constraints, I will have to stick with Eclipse at the moment until I can get a break from React Development with VSCode.